# Setting Fabric.js canvas background with unsaved webcam image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using the [Media Capture and Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Capture_and_Streams_API) to initialize the webcam and allow users to capture photos from the webcam stream. I'm also experimenting with [Fabric.js](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js) to allow users to edit/markup the photos. My HTML has a canvas element and a video element like so:

```
<canvas id="img-canvas"> </canvas>
<video id="img-stream" autoplay></video>
```

I start the webcam like so:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
        const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
        video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       // error
    });
```

And capture photos from the live feed like so:

```
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
return canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // returns a base64 string that can be used to set <img> src
```

And initialize the fabric canvas like so:

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas("img-canvas");
```

The problem I have is using Fabric.js to add shapes and other fabric objects to the canvas. As soon as I add something, my image disappears. For instance trying to add a circle with:

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
    id: "circle1",
    left: canvas.width / 2,
    top: canvas.height / 2,
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    stroke: 'red',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    radius: 20
}));
```

I've also tried using Fabric.js to set the background of the canvas to the image, but it seems it needs a valid URL:

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageData, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

They list other ways of setting adding an image that takes an actual `<img>` element, so I set an `<img>` tag's source to the `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` result (which works for the `<img>` element) but I'm still got getting the image added to my canvas:

```
var cvsimg = document.getElementById("captured-img");
var image = new fabric.Image(cvsimg, {
    opacity: 1,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
});
canvas.add(image);
```

In summary, I need a way to add Fabric.js objects to my existing `<canvas>` without the image disappearing OR a way to set the canvas background using Fabric.js and an image that isn't saved anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a camera at the moment, but I tested my code on an mp4 video and I have the video showing in the background, I can also move the red square while the video is running and all is well.

I wrote a class and wrote in the render method - drawImage and added the very first object to the canvas

Here is the resulting code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="img-stream" src="video.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="img-canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('img-canvas', {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            selectionColor: 'rgba(100,100,100,0.3)', // selection with opacity 0.3
            selectionLineWidth: 2,
            width: window.outerWidth,
            height: window.outerHeight,
            viewportTransform: [1, 0, 0, 1, -window.outerWidth/2, -window.outerHeight/2],
            //stopContextMenu: true, // prevent the right-click context menu from appearing
            fireRightClick: true, // enable firing of right click events
            fireMiddleClick: true, // enable firing of middle click events

        });

        const video = document.getElementById("img-stream");

        var fabricBGStream = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
            type: 'fabricBGStream',
    
            initialize: function () {
        
            },
    
            render: function (ctx) {
                ctx.save();
                //ctx.drawImage(video, -canvas.viewportTransform[4], -canvas.viewportTransform[5], canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(video, -canvas.viewportTransform[4], -canvas.viewportTransform[5], video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
                ctx.restore();
            }
        });

        var bg = new fabricBGStream();

        canvas.add(bg);

        var rec = new fabric.Rect({
            left: -canvas.viewportTransform[4],
            top: -canvas.viewportTransform[5],
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            selectable: true,
            evented: true,
            draggable: true,
            angle: 0
        });

        canvas.add(rec);

        canvas.renderAll();

        var requestVideo = null;

        function captureFrame() { 
            canvas.renderAll();
            requestVideo = requestAnimationFrame(captureFrame);
        }

        video.onplaying = function(e) {
            captureFrame();
        }

        video.addEventListener("play", function() {    
            //captureFrame();
        });

        video.addEventListener("pause", function() {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestVideo);
        });

        
        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then((stream) => {
                const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // error
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also override the built-in private method instead of creating a separate class, like this:

```
canvas._renderBackground = function(ctx) {
    if (!this.backgroundColor) {
        return;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
    ctx.fillRect(
        0,
        0,
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height
    );
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    //ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

But I don't recommend doing that